# Applied Solution Based On Polya Enumeration Theorem

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, mathematics

## Problem

A function solution(w, h, s) that takes 3 integers and returns the number of unique, non-equivalent configurations that can be found on a grid w blocks wide, h blocks tall and s possible states.

Equivalency is defined as above: any two grids each with same state where the actual order of the rows and columns do not matter (and can thus be freely swapped around).

Grid standardization means that the width and height of the grid will always be between 1 and 12, inclusive. The number of states is between 2 and 20, inclusive.

Return it as a decimal string.

#### Example Cases

- Case 1: w=2, h=2, s=2; answer:7
- Case 2: w=2, h=3, s=4; answer:430

## Solution

The solution can be built based on Group Theory, specifically from Pólya Enumeration theorem.

#### Brief Theory Description

The Pólya enumeration theorem is a generalization of Burnside's lemma which provides a more convenient tool for finding the number of equivalence classes.

Burnside’s Lemma is also sometimes known as orbit counting theorem. It is one of the results of group theory. It is used to count distinct objects with respect to symmetry. It basically gives us the formula to count the total number of combinations, where two objects that are symmetrical to each other with respect to rotation or reflection are counted as a single representative.

There is a set (the whole set of h x w-matrices, where the entries can take any of s different values) and a group of permutations that transforms some matrices in others. In the problem the group consists of all permutations of rows and/or columns of the matrices.

The set of matrices gets divided into classes of matrices that can be transformed into one another. The goal of the problem is to count the number of these classes. In technical terminology the set of classes is called the quotient of the set by the action of the group, or orbit space.

The good thing is that there is a powerful theorem (with many generalizations and versions) that does exactly that. That is Polya's enumeration theorem. The theorem expresses the number of elements of the orbit space in terms of the value of a polynomial known in the area as Cycle Index. Now, in this problem the group is a direct product of two special groups the group of all permutations of h and w elements, respectively. The Cycle Index polynomials for these groups are known, and so are formulas for computing the Cycle Index polynomial of the product of groups in terms of the Cycle Index polynomials of the factors.

Maybe a comment worth making that motivates the name of the polynomial is the following: Every permutation of elements can be seen as cycling disjoint subsets of those elements. For example, a permutation of (1,2,3,4,5) and can be (2,3,1,5,4), where we mean that 2 moved to the position of 1, 3 moved to the position of 2, 1 to the position of 3, 5 to the position of 4 and 4 to the position of 5. The effect of this permutation is the same as cycling 1-> 3 -> 2 and 2 back to 1, and cycling 4 -> 5 and 5 back to 4. Similar to how natural numbers can be factored into a product of prime factors, each permutation can be factored into disjoint cycles. For each permutation, the cycles are unique in a sense for each permutation. The Cycle Index polynomial is computed in terms of the number of cycles of each length for each permutation in the group.

#### Pseudocode Overview

- Partitions of a number
- Greatest common divisors (gcd) of many numbers.
- Factorials of many numbers.

## Code

```
from collections import Counter

def solution(w, h, s):    
    grid=0
    for pw in partitions(w):
        for ph in partitions(h):            
            m=count(pw, w)*count(ph, h)
            grid+=m*(s**sum([sum([gcd(i, j) for i in pw]) for j in ph]))
    
    return str(grid//(factorial(w)*factorial(h)))
    
def count(c, n):
    cnt=factorial(n)
    for a, b in Counter(c).items():
        cnt//=(a**b)*factorial(b)
    return cnt        

def partitions(n, i=1):
    yield [n]
    for i in range(i, n//2 + 1):
        for p in partitions(n-i, i):
            yield [i] + p

def gcd(x,y):
    while y:
        x,y=y,x%y
    return x

def factorial(n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*factorial(n-1)
```